# Why does MySQL Workbench GUI update does not work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I selected a table in mysql workbench by running a query like:

```
select * from table1
```

From the results grid I made some updates to the result. However, when I run the query again non of my updates are there anymore?

Is it possible to add or edit result from MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Did you click away from the row before performing the query? Sounds like you didn't actually submit the changes. Right now we don't have enough information to help you. (Obviously, row updates work in general or the product would be useless.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: after edit the row press on apply]
after edit the row press on apply Then apply the script on the DataBase